# Firebase! How to increment icon badge count when app is inactive, active and not launched?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

Need to update new push notifcation count to icon badge.
Is there a way to increment notification count from firebase push 
and should work even when the app is not launched.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound,.badge])
}
```